how to check for duplicates in random value and return value in loop
i want a function that generate a random value and stord it in array but should check that the value is not repeated also returned every value after check
int random_function() {
    const int size = 80;
    int arr[80];
    int i = 1;

    srand(time(0));
    int session = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        session = rand();
        session = arr[i] for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                i--;
            }
        }
        return session
    }

    return -1;
}


Please check the formatting. In any case, what is your question? What works? What doesn't? Just to get that clear, any local array is destroyed on function exit. Also, you should not repeatedly call srand(), as it's counterproductive. For C++, there are better alternatives to rand()/srand(), too.

@UlrichEckhardt thanks but what about my question how ican solve it?

Did you mean for the function to have "memory" so that it never repeats the same number within the next 80 calls?

@TedLyngmo ineed to use it in another function

Sidenote: srand(time(0)); should only be called once for the whole program run. Put it first in main and never call it again.

@TedLyngmo okay but for my question

What actually is your question? The two questions from the title? Please don't ask multiple questions at once. Also, state clearly what your question is, a title is still just a teaser to the text, not a replacement of a fundamental part thereof. For reference, take the [tour] and read [ask].

What do you want to return, single int or array? How should this function be used?

@Yksisarvinen iwant to return the session and stored it in array

Are you generating exactly 80 random numbers, and want them to be distinct, or are you generating more, and want a sliding window of 80 non-duplicate?

@rose Do not change the target language after you've gotten answers. Ask a new question if you are not capable of depickling the algorithm in the answer you've gotten in order to make something similar in C.

@TedLyngmo what ishould do then ?

do an int array 1..n, then shuffle it by doing random index.

Since your function requires to remember the 80 last generated numbers in order to avoid returning one of those, you could make the array static and keep a static index where you write the new number for each call.
Here's an example:
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int random_function() {
    static std::array<int, 80> arr = [] {
        std::array<int, 80> rv;
        rv.fill(-1);  // can't be returned by `rand`
        return rv;
    }();
    static unsigned idx = 0;

    int session;
    do {
        session = rand();
        // check if the generated number is among the 80 last generated
        // and if it is, try again:
    } while (std::find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), session) != arr.end());

    arr[idx] = session;           // store the number
    idx = (idx + 1) % arr.size(); // and step the index before the next call

    return session;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i) {
        std::cout << random_function() << '\n'; // 80 unique numbers
    }
}


thanks but can you give me a solution in c not c++ ?

@rose I would have done that if the question was a C question. It is however a C++ question. ... an no, don't change the tag now after you've gotten an answer to the question you asked.

ihave changed it i need a solution today cause i should finish my task

@rose The implementation example is mostly there for support and it shouldn't be too hard to implement something similar in C. You need static storage where you store the numbers and then just look in that array when you generate a new number. If it's already in there, try again, until you get a number that is not in the array. Then store that number, step the index and return the newly stored number.

but i want the boucle for inside the function

@rose You are trying to finish a school assignment on time I assume and it may be stressful, but all the clues you need are in the answer even if you happen to want do it slightly differently for some reason. If the purpose of the function is to generate 80 unique numbers and return those, you don't need static storage at all. Just supply a pointer to the array you want to fill and fill it while checking if the generated number is already in the array.
